# Get the latest data - optimize the SQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using the following SQL query in order to get the latest data from the database.

```
SELECT d.id AS id_d,
       d.id_user AS id_du,
       d.id_channel AS id_dc,
       d.datetime_logged AS logged

FROM discord AS d
JOIN discord_users AS du
ON d.id_user = du.id
WHERE datetime_logged IN (SELECT MAX(datetime_logged) FROM discord)
ORDER BY du.data_name ASC
```

And here's how the database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discord` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_channel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_game` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_muted_server` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_muted_self` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_deafen_server` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_deafen_self` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_suppressed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `data_game` text,
  `datetime_logged` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discord_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_id` text NOT NULL,
  `data_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `data_avatar` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

That query takes "ages" to load. But if I remove `WHERE datetime_logged IN (SELECT MAX(datetime_logged) FROM discord)` and add `LIMIT 10` to the query, the page loads super fast!

---

The purpose of the SQL query is to get only the latest data from the table `discord`. Since the data will only update every 15 minute, the query will easily pick up the latest data.

The relationship with `discord` and `discord_users` is that `discord` needs the ID from `discord_users` in order to get the information from an user.

To answer symcbean's questions futhermore:

**Q)** Why, when you are aapparently restricting the ouput to a single record based on the content of the "many" side of the relationship, are you ordering by the "one" side?

**A)** What do you mean?

**Q)** Why are you opening 2 cursors on the discord_users table in the absence of differential indexes on the table?

**A)** Once again, what do you mean? :)

---

So here's my question. How can I optimize my SQL query so it dosen't takes almost 1 minute to load the page? Here's a link to the page: https://erik-edgren.nu/discord

Comment: Have you index on `datetime_logged`?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know exactly what mean. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Refer to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! But which index should I use?

Comment: How many records/rows does your table have?

Comment: Over 3 000 rows and counting.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I have added the index now and the page loads very fast now. Many thanks! But since your answer is a comment, I'll accept jonju's answer.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY`.  So get rid of the redundant `UNIQUE` keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have the issue try this option. Create an `INDEX` say e.g `index_datelog` on the column `datetime_logged` of `discord` table. And then try below query

```
SELECT 
    d.id AS id_d, d.id_user AS id_du, d.id_channel AS id_dc, d.datetime_logged AS logged 
FROM 
    discord d 
JOIN 
    discord_users du ON d.id_user = du.id USE INDEX(index_datelog))
WHERE 
    d. datetime_logged = (SELECT MAX(datetime_logged) FROM discord)
ORDER BY d.datetime_logged ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created the index (it was easier than I thought. I must have been too tired last night) and the page loads very fast now with my SQL query. Your query trows an error; `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(INDEX(index_datelog)) WHERE d. datetime_logged = (SELECT MAX(datetime_l' at line 7' in`

Comment: Oh! thank you for pointing. That was the syntax of MSSQL. Updated the answer with MySql syntax

Comment: Forcing an index is very bad practice and should not be necessary (sometimes it proves necessary but only on the back of empirical evidence). Also a hash index would be useless - it requires a BTree index. Also the sorting is changed from the original query.